# Um método matemático para saber quantos carrys em uma soma

Tags: matemática, independente-de-linguagem

Vi hoje no **URI** (site de problemas de programação) uma questão na qual o seu programa deveria ler dois valores e dizer quantos *carrys* (ou "vai um"s) acontecem na soma deles. Ex: 555 + 555 = 3 *carrys* e 1 + 9999999 = 7 *carrys*.

Eu fiz um programa pra calcular manualmente, igual um ser humano, primeiro eu igualei a quantidade de casas decimais usando um *for* e depois eu fiz a soma manual. Ex: 12 999999 = 000012 999999 e depois era efetuada a soma.
Porém um pessoal falou que existia uma maneira de responder isso muito mais eficiente e eu gostaria de saber como é, procurei no google mas não achei em lugar algum, acredito que seja parecido com a maneira de descobrir quantos zeros existem em um número fatorial([Determinar zeros de fatorial](http://www.tutorbrasil.com.br/forum/matematica-ensino-medio/fatorial-t16640.html)).

Comment: Olá amigo, sobre dúvidas com o URI você pode acessar direto o fórum do site - https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/forum/ - , é mais fácil de alguém te ajudar por lá por muitas pessoas já terem resolvido os MESMOS problemas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não entendi 100% a solução matemática do Leo, talvez seja o mesmo que vou mostrar aqui. Encontrei no site Math Overflow uma [discussão](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218604/is-the-number-of-carries-in-integer-addition-associative) que indica haver uma relação entre entre o número de *carries* e as somas dos dígitos de cada operando e do resultado. Esta fórmula é citada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

S<sub>b</sub> representa uma soma de dígitos na base *b*; *a* e *c* são os operandos da adição, e *k* é o número de *carries*. Rearranjando a fórmula para isolar *k*, e considerando que você está trabalhando na base 10, teremos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma implementação em C, como exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int teste1 = carries(9, 1);
    int teste2 = carries(99, 1);
    int teste3 = carries(999, 1);
    int teste4 = carries(999, 10);

    printf("9+1: %i carries\n", teste1);
    printf("99+1: %i carries\n", teste2);
    printf("999+1: %i carries\n", teste3);
    printf("999+10: %i carries\n", teste4);

    return 0;
}

int carries(int a, int b) {
    return (sumDigits(a) + sumDigits(b) - sumDigits(a+b)) / 9;
}

int sumDigits(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        sum += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

http://ideone.com/P8OZ5t

Comment: Ótimo! Tem uma forma melhor ainda de fazer, mas a galera top do URI não quer revelar

Comment: Se descobrir, posta uma resposta aqui!

Comment: vou tentar adicionar algum no facebook!

Answer (score 1):

Se é que eu entendi seu problema, acredito que capturando a **expressão** como "**string**" e tratando com um contador, duas variáveis de controle e algumas variáveis auxiliares seja mais eficiente.

**Minha sugestão é desenvolver um algoritmo da seguinte forma:**

Serão necessárias **duas variáveis de controle**, uma para **registrar o dígito com a maior quantidade de Carrys** na expressão (caso ocorra) e outra para **registrar o respectivo dígito** desta ocorrência.

Devem haver variáveis auxiliares, como para o **contador do "loop"** que deve "varrer" a "string" da expressão caractere por caracter da esquerda para a direita, de um até a quantidade de caracteres da expressão, por exemplo, para  "**12 + 999999**" será de **1** até **11**.

Sempre que ocorrer a sequência de um mesmo digito, **registre a quantidade somando 1** em uma variável auxiliar e em outra variável auxiliar **registre qual é esse dígito**.

**Quando o próximo dígito for diferente do anterior**, verifique se a **quantidade da variável auxiliar é maior que a registrada na variável de controle**, se não for, **zere as variáveis auxiliares** e continue, se for a maior quantidade, **registre ela na variável de controle** como **também na outra variável de controle qual é esse dígito**. Se for o mesmo dígito irá sobrepor, então não haverá problema, como é o caso de "**555 + 555**".

espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Na verdade eu citei ali que eu tinha conseguido resolver o problema recebendo por string, mas ai onde ta, eu queria uma forma matemática de resolver isso, por string já vira um algorítmo de TI

Answer (score 1):

Atenção, posso ter interpretado mal a questão e esta solução pode não apresentar Carrys pelo método matemático.

A solução matemática que deseja e que eu desenvolvi (desconheço se alguém já fez isso antes, pois sou engenheiro e não matemático, se alguém tiver uma referência, favor informar nos comentários, que faço questão de analisar e citar aqui nesta resposta) é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo um exemplo com as fórmulas das células apresentadas ao lado (neste exemplo, a coluna é "I" e a linha dos dados iniciais é 13)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como os cálculos funcionam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Primeiro é preciso calcular a quantidade de dígitos do número a ser analisado, isto é feito por meio da parte inteira do resultado do logaritmo de base 10 desse número mais um.

O logaritmo de base 10, para valores como 10, 100 e 1000 só retorna números inteiros, respectivamente 1, 2 e 3 neste exemplo (suas respectivas potências).

Assim, um valor inteiro que esteja entre 10 ^ 3  (1000) e  10 ^ 4 (10000), terá o resultado de seu logaritmo de base 10 entre 3 e 4, nunca 3 (seria 1000) ou 4 (seria 10000).

Desta forma, acima de 1000 (que tem quatro dígitos, igual à sua potência mais um) e abaixo de 10000 (que tem cinco dígitos, igual à sua potência mais um), todos os valores inteiros neste intervalo obrigatoriamente terão quatro dígitos, e o resultado de seus logaritmos serão sempre maiores do que 3 e menores do que 4.

Portanto, pegando a parte inteira deste cálculo e somando um, obtemos o número de dígitos do número inteiro analisado.

Para ser um Carry, todos os dígitos devem ser iguais, então, obtendo o primeiro dígito deste número podemos gerar um Carry com ele (de mesmo números de dígitos do valor original) e comparar se são iguais.

Pegando a parte inteira do resultado da divisão deste valor por 10 elevado ao seu número de dígitos e multiplicando por 10, obtêm-se um número inteiro que é o primeiro dígito do valor analisado.

Para repetir este dígito pela quantidade de dígitos do valor analisado, é preciso obter o mesmo número de 1s, para que, ao multiplicar por este primeiro dígito, o resultado retorne seu respectivo Carry.

Como 1/9 dá uma dízima de 1s, basta pegar a quantidade de 1s necessária para a multiplicação.

Isto é feito pelo cálculo da parte inteira da dízima vezes 10 elevado ao número de dígitos.

Ao multiplicar o primeiro dígito pelos 1s, obtêm-se o Carry.

Ao subtrair o valor do Carry obtido pelo valor analisado, se o resultado for zero, trata-se de um Carry, senão não é um Carry.

A quantidade de dígitos deve ser considerada quando se obtêm o Carry.

Faça isso para cada parte da sua equação!

Comment: A tabela tinha uma falha na apresentação das respostas, já corrigi.

Comment: Oi Leo. Dê uma olhada na minha resposta, veja se bate com o que você disse. Não consegui ter certeza – deve ser porque não sou engenheiro :)

Comment: kkkkk, boa @bfavaretto, eu não uso esta linguagem, então, gostaria de saber se os resultados bateram, inclusive para os mesmos exemplos que apresentei, no entanto, não há nestas equações os elementos que apresentei em minha solução, portanto, continua sem referência (pode ser que eu tenha criado algo novo...)

Comment: Então, é que eu não entendi sua resposta, nem a tabela. A pergunta fala de quantos "vai n" (carries) existem numa operação de soma. A sua tabela tem números soltos.

Comment: Não é isso, está tudo em fórmulas do Excel e a explicação dos cálculos está na própria tabela abaixo de cada legenda de linha. Vou rever mais tarde e editarei, aceito sugestões.

Comment: Quais números soltos? Não entendi? Somente os número iniciais (cabeçalho de cada coluna) é informado, o resto é calculado pelas fórmulas apresentadas, são todos resultados!

Comment: A adição no caso seria por exemplo `9999999 + 55555`?

Comment: Ok, coloquei como exemplo quatro valores distintos para mostrar que o método funciona. Como o Ícaro disse lá trás, ele tem o código que "lê" a expressão e não é isso que ele queria (veja minha primeira resposta). Assim, ao separar cada grupo de números, basta aplicar meu método, é isso.

Comment: Pronto, agora fica visualmente fácil entender o que expliquei textualmente abaixo. Veja o que acha.

Comment: Leo, o que eu não entendo é como um número pode "ter" carries. Pra mim os carries só existem no momento da adição, pra existir eles dependem dos 2 operandos. Obrigado pelo esforço pra me explicar, eu é que estou com dificuldade de raciocínio :)

Comment: Não amigo, eu que devo ter confundido mesmo, como disse, não sou matemático, e me empolguei, pois adoro encontrar soluções para problemas matemáticos e lógicos, e aqui me vi diante de um desses possíveis casos. Interpretei mal a questão, me desculpe.